# 503 Error with vertx applicatoin

Tags: http-status-code-503, vert.x

I am uploading my first vertx project to Openshift.
The vertx project runs fine on my laptop.

When I push it using git to openshift and try to load a webpage I get a 503 error.

I did rhc tail:

```
==> vertx/logs/console.log <==
GOT CONFIG: {"index_page":"index.html","host":"localhost","port":443,"ssl":true,
"key_store_password":"0449666331abcdef$","key_store_path":"colomedia.tv-key.keys
tore","bridge":true,"inbound_permitted":[{"address":"colo.listboxes"},{"address"
:"colo.rebootbox"},{"address":"colo.addbox"}]}
/usr/bin/tail: vertx/logs/vertx.log: file truncated

==> vertx/logs/console.log <==
Succeeded in deploying verticle

==> vertx/logs/vertx.log <==
[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] 2014-11-29T13:58:43.786-05:00 INFO [org.vertx.java.p
latform.impl.cli.Starter]  Succeeded in deploying verticle

==> vertx/logs/console.log <==
colo: Connector deployed
```

Which all looks like it is fine.

Please can you help in any way?

Many thanks
James

Comment: The issue was that I was trying to use explicit port and IP values for my httpserver instead of using the openshift environment variables. The below fixed it
'<p>var ip = container.env[‘OPENSHIFT_VERTX_IP’] || ‘127.0.0.1’;<br>var port = parseInt(container.env[‘OPENSHIFT_VERTX_PORT’] || 8080);'